# collapse components on click horizontally accoridion style

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have 3 component window  utilizing vuetify v-data tables,

I'd like to add a button on my third component to expand it and to full size of browser and collapse the other two components in a vertical accordion style . Is using the navigation drawer the best idea ? Vuetify has collapsible components that work horizontally only at the moment.

basic component structure :

```
   <template>
     <v-data-table>
     </v-data-table> 
        <template>
```